# What to use: Xpath or CSS selector while scraping Linkedin?

Tags: web-scraping

i want to scrape Linkedins activity posts - comments, number of views and so on.
What selenium method to choose: Xpath or CSS?
I am trying to do this with Xpath but i have hmm the strange feeling that it is changing based on profile, language and chrome version.... How to do this for general usage?

Can anybody advice?

Answer (score 1):

Xpath can change with the execution of javascript or can be different on different profiles. If the only chance is using xpath, then it is ok but if there is an id or special class you should use them.

In selenium, you have multiple options to select an element by id.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ember87')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ember87']")
```

And of course you can use any other css selector and generally this is the convenient way.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ember87")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#ember87")
```

Also you can use the parent element to make selection more special and more convenient.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ember72>#ember87")
```

Comment: thanks! 

this "ember87" is also changable? 


"Xpath can change with the execution of javascript or can be different on different profiles." --> o wow this can be harmful - if i will create tool it can work only in my environment. So Xpath is only specific for specific environments?

Comment: "ember87" is an id of an element from linkedin homepage. In html, elements can have an id and generally this id is given to indicate that element specifically. So "id" does not change with the events. We can't say xpath changes with everything. For example, on a login page xpaths usually remains constant but in a product page it can be change with the discount of price because the discount percentage can add a new element to that block.

Comment: thank you ibra. In this case with example for percentage - how to catch this kind of stuff then?

Comment: Anyone Can answer?